# flask wtf- forms doesnt appear on HTML using flask/jinja

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

i am trying to create an app which supposed to have a form field. i've been using flask wtf for this and i cant fix it. the form doesnt appeae on the html (only the extended base appears)

this is my HTML code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if name %}
  <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
{% else %}
  <h1>What's your name?</h1>
  <br/>
  <form method="post" action="novalidate">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.name.label }}
    {{ form.name() }}
    <br/>
    {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
{% endif %}


{% endblock content %}
```

and this is the relevant code on python:

```
`# Form
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("What's your name?", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/name', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def name():
    form = NameForm()
    name = " "
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
        return redirect(url_for('user', name=name))
    return render_template('name.html', form=form, name=name)
```

i tried moving the form html code to a page without jinja (extends base..) and it worked. but i need it to work with jinja&flask. what am i doing wrong?